# I am having this issue, 'NameError: uninitialized constant Profile::friend', when running 'rake db:seed'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nameerror

Console Error

> /puppyPals console$ rake db:seed
>       rake aborted!
>       NameError: uninitialized constant Profile::friend
>       /Desktop/puppyPals/puppyPals/app/models/profile.rb:8:in `follow'
>       /Desktop/puppyPals/puppyPals/db/seeds.rb:31:in `block in '
>       /Desktop/puppyPals/puppyPals/db/seeds.rb:31:in `each'
>       /Desktop/puppyPals/puppyPals/db/seeds.rb:31:in `
>
> #app/models/profile.rb
>       class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
>           has_many :friends, class_name:  "friend", foreign_key: "follower_id",
>               dependent:   :destroy
>           has_many :following, through: :friends, source: :followed

```
    # Follows a profile.
    def follow(other_profile)
        friends.create(followed_id: other_profile.id)
    end

    # Unfollows a user.
    def unfollow(other_profile)
        friends.find_by(followed_id: other_profile.id).destroy
    end

    # Returns true if the current user is following the other user.
    def following?(other_profile)
        following.include?(other_profile)
    end
end

#Seeds.rb
Profile.create!(first_name:  "First",
             last_name: "Last",
             dog_name:  "Dog")

99.times do |n|
    first  = "name-#{n}"
    last = "last"
    dog = "dog"
    Profile.create!(first_name: first,
                 last_name: last,
                 dog_name: dog)
end

profiles = Profile.all
profile  = profiles.first
following = profiles[2..50]
followers = profiles[3..40]
following.each { |followed| profile.follow(followed) }
followers.each { |follower| follower.follow(profile) }
```

Comment: `class_name` should be proper case e.g. `class_name: 'Friend'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly define your `class_name` for your Friend model. It should change to:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friends, class_name:  "Friend", foreign_key: "follower_id",
        dependent:   :destroy
  # ...
end
```

[Read more about the `class_name` argument here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-class-name).